# How i can display data from oracle tovb.net in textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net

I would like to display the multiple records in multiple textboxes
Following is my tables and data:

tblJan with these data:
(col id
1
2
3)...
(col January
10
20
30)...

now i want to display the value 10 in one textbox and the value 20 in another textbox and so with the value 30 in another textbox..

i am new in vb.net and a help would be greatly appreciated..tnx..

Comment: You'll need to show some code and be specific about any issues you're having.

Comment: Have you run a `SELECT query` on the database table to get the data in a `DataSet`/`DataTable` yet?

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not a code writing service. You're going to have to research this and come back when you have a specific issue. Have a look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you'll need to do, if you haven't done so already, is run a `SELECT` query on the database table to get the data that you want, and store it in a `DataSet` or a `DataTable`. To find out more about doing this, use [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/select.php).

Next, you'll need to get the variable that you're storing in the `TextBox` from the `DataSet`/`DataTable`, using something along the lines of

```
Dim myVar as String = ""
myVar = myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("myField")

TextBox1.Text = myVar
```

It's really as simple as that - Although in future, please try for yourself and then post a question with any issues, rather than asking for it just from scratch.

Comment: Thank you David i will try your solution